# How can I create a DataTable from an XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datatable

I asked a similar question recently, but it turns out that I had the wrong idea going into it, so the answer to the question I asked was not exactly what I was looking for. I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items found="132" limit="1000">
    <sampleField>
        <att1>18
        </att1>
        <att2>4343
        </att2>
        <att3>94007961
        </att3>
        <att4>Test
        </att4>
        <att5>Example
        </att5>
   </sampleField>

   <sampleField>
        <att1>40
        </att1>
        <att2>8945
        </att2>
        <att3>94089741
        </att3>
        <att4>Test2
        </att4>
        <att5>Example2
        </att5>
   </sampleField>
</items>
```

I want to create a DataTable (that will later be converted to a SQL Server database table) with the column names being the tag names of the children of one of the `<sampleField>` elements. The actual values of the `<att#>` elements should represent the different rows in the table. The table should look like this:

[image]

How could I go about creating this DataTable from this XML file in C#? I have tried `dataTable.ReadXML()`, but I got an error message that said this: `DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml`. I have also tried using a DataSet to get around this error, but it created two different tables. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you change from your earlier posting?  The code was working before!!!

Comment: @jdweng You're right. It was working before. I was attempting to test it by printing out the results of the table the wrong way (which makes me feel pretty dumb). Your answer to my other question was correct. I will accept it if you would like to make your comment the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the required table from table collections

```
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(@"XML PATH");
  var dataTable=  ds.Tables[1]
```

**Update**

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
  {
   foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
   {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
   }
  }
```

**Using Linq**
You can also use linq for parsing the xml

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"a.xml");
    var table = from x in doc.Descendants("sampleField")
                select new
                {
                    Attr1 = x.Element("att1").Value,
                    Attr2 = x.Element("att2").Value,
                    Attr3 = x.Element("att3").Value,
                    Attr4 = x.Element("att4").Value,
                    Attr5 = x.Element("att5").Value,


                };
```

Comment: How could I print the rows and columns of this DataTable to see if it works?

Comment: The Visual Studio debugger has a nice viewer for Datatables. Put a break on your code and mouse over the dataTable variable and then click the magnifying class to see a grid of the datatable's contents.

Comment: @esmoore68 I didn't know that. This is a Windows service project (it has no GUI). Does that change things with the DataTable?

Comment: As long as you're using VS to design and debug, should work regardless of project type.

Comment: @esmoore68 You're a lifesaver. This answer and your comment solved my problem. Thanks to everyone! The visualization tool in the VS debugger is very helpful!